# RSpec and Rack middleware: how to make sure that it is active in a spec/dummy request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, middleware

I have a Rack middleware that inserts itself automatically into the app when the gem is specified within the Gemfile:

```
gem 'headhunter'
```

Then the middleware registers itself like this:

```
module Headhunter
  module Rails
    class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
      initializer "headhunter.hijack" do |app|
        head_hunter = Runner.new(::Rails.root)

        at_exit do
          head_hunter.report
          head_hunter.clean_up!
        end

        app.middleware.insert(0, Headhunter::Rack::CapturingMiddleware, head_hunter)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to make sure that the middleware is actually inserted in an RSpec feature/request spec.

I have a dummy Rails app in `spec/dummy` which does the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Middleware integration' do
  scenario "Integrating the middleware into the Rack stack" do
    expect(Headhunter::Rack::CapturingMiddleware.any_instance).to receive(:call)
    visit posts_path
  end
end
```

Sadly this fails and I don't know why. By placing a `binding.pry` within `call` I can tell for sure that it **is** called.

Is there maybe even a better way to test this? Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: try `expect(Headhunter::Rack::CapturingMiddleware).to receive(:call)`

Comment: Gives the same result. But 1 upvote for the newer RSpec syntax. :)